# AngularJS ng-click not working after click

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with ngClick on my view. When I click on the button, nothing happens.

My button on my view:

```
<md-button ng-if="active('user.asker')" aria-label="Editer" type="button" placeholder="exemple@exemple.com" ng-click="updateProfileConfirmation()">
      My button
</md-button>
```

And my controller :

```
module.exports = function ($scope) {
    "ngInject"

    $scope.updateProfileConfirmation = () => {
        console.log($scope);
    }
}
```

There's something there that I missed ?

Comment: $scope.updateProfileConfirmation = () => { // what's this ?

Comment: @EduardUta That's how you define function in ES6

Comment: @EduardUta https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: does your browser supports latest ES6 code ??

Comment: Is `mdButton` a custom directive that you have defined by yourself?

Comment: I've never defined angular controller in this way: `module.exports = function ($scope) {...}`.  Normally it is defined like `angular.module(...).controller(...)`.

Comment: The controller is defined on a state :
`state({
        name: 'user.asker.parameters.account',
        url: '/account',
        views: {
            "content": {
                controller: require('./controllers/common/Account.js'),
                template: require('./views/common/account.html')
            }
        }
    })`

Comment: @firestqr : can you show us your `ng-controller` in html and `angular.module(...).controller()`